# Moderators removing individual comments which do not fall outside of known guidelines or rules

Tags: discussion, comments, moderators, deleted-comments

I would like to know why some of my comments are being removed from questions posted to Stack Overflow.

There has been one in the last few hours, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73669661), which I have reposted, *(not word for word)*.

There was another, just a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73614812) too, which included information used to improve the answer. I subsequently reposted and explained the information over a few comments afterwards, which I personally deleted in agreement with the answer author when we cleaned up their accepted answer for future users.

I have no issues with the delete all comments method used by moderator, or with those multi-flagged, but these did not fall into those categories.

My only thought right now is that one particular moderator is singling out specific members for personal reasons, or as a favor to someone, not due to site rules; or that there are multiple moderators who are exercising their power outside of their remit, and being allowed to continue doing so without oversight.

Could somebody please look into what's going on, and have this behavior corrected.

Comment: Comments are temporary by design, so all comments are subject to deletion. From the help center: “Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.”

Comment: Yes, please keep filling your subsequent/reposted comments with attacks against moderators. This gives us a very clear justification for continuing to delete them within the known guidelines and rules. (Also, your original comment was flagged as "no longer needed", which the mod who deleted it was responding to. Since that fact disproves the claims in this question, does that end the discussion?)

Comment: If that was tje case in the first example, the comment before mine, which had not beed upvoted, would have been deleted too. That sir is an excuse, not a reason. There are existing comments on this site from years ago, and no excuse to remove individual ones which do not breach any rules, provide possibly very important information to the OP, and future viewers. There is also no reason to not allow other members to counter comment, or provide feedback on that comment over a period of just a few hours, especially on a quiet weekend. How about reasons and fixes, instead of excuses?

Comment: Well, no, because that comment before yours wasn't flagged.

Comment: Those comments are not attacking Moderators, they are questioning their actions @CodyGray. There is a difference, and your comment shows that you do not know that. The mention of it is not an attack of a group, it is there for the self improvement of the Moderator who is overstepping their remit, and as a reminder to others not to follow suit. Mine wasn't flagged either, and if it was, tje flag should have been ignored, because it did not do anything wrong. A comment shouldn't be deleted for a flag, until the readon for that is proven to be a rule/guideline breach, those were not.

Comment: Comments on a question complaining about meta-actions taken by moderators are off-topic and an inappropriate use of comments, whether you like the word "attack" or not. No comments have been deleted on this Meta question, which is a more appropriate forum to complain about moderator actions. I don't particularly like or recommend the accusatory tone that you've taken, but, in my opinion, it's narrowly within the bounds of acceptability *on Meta*.

Comment: Let's be clear here, if a comment has been deleted which did not fall outside of the rules, in a very very short period of time after posting, by a single Moderator, then yes I am accusing that specific Moderator of either a complete lack of care and attention, or simply overstepping their remit. When it happens occasionally, and it has, I let it go, now it's becoming more frequent, and as such I've raised it as an official issue. Sort it out instead of trying to justify it.

Comment: I'm not trying to justify anything. I haven't even read your original comment. I don't have any opinion on whether its deletion was justifiable or not. What I was attempting to convey to you was that it is not a winning strategy to leave additional comments complaining about moderators scattered about posts on the main site. I deleted those comments, and I will continue to delete any more that you decide to leave, and I will do so with full justification of the rules and guidelines and everything else. You can continue to rant here, though. Hope you get it sorted out.

Comment: So, whilst my complaint is on this particular platform, you decided to delete my comment in each if the linked questions too. Now, I understand that you have a problem with complaints about Moderator actions, and have deleted those as a result. But as those 'complaints' formed only part of the comments, you have now removed the valid information too, which proved that what I had posted was valid and not against any rules. Please do not pretend that you can discuss these things transparently, when you've already done everything you can to weight everything in your own favor.

Comment: You can't make your invalid comments invulnerable to deletion by adding some valid part to them.

Comment: There was no reason why you couldn't have asked me to repost those comments minus the 'complaints' part, before you deleted them in their entirety. That would have been courteous as part of this discussion, and shown true transparency. Am I now expected to take additional time to make my comment for a third time, to help the OP and the site, or do you want the question, OP and future users to never see that valid and important information, at the detriment of the sire/readership?

Comment: "_But as those 'complaints' formed only part of the comments_" that's not true the comment in the second linked post was entirely a complaint. Also the problem is not with you complaining about moderator actions, it is with you doing it in the wrong place. Appropriate ways are: raise a flag / use the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form / post on meta

Comment: Can you link or clarify what the "known guidelines or rules" are? It looks almost as if you're referring to guidelines or rules none of us are aware exist.

Comment: I actually thought about removing the first half that complained about mods, but I didn't want to give you any more fodder for complaining about mods. You can take or not take whatever time you like to post on-topic comments, but if you include inappropriate things in those comments, they're going to be deleted as well. Anyway, I'm growing a bit tired of this ego trip where you pretend everything you're doing is for the good of others, and we stupid mods are robbing the world of your great wisdom by removing off-topic rants. Is it possible you could just inquire, without casting aspersions?

Comment: I'm trying it here @AbdulAzizBarkat, supposedly the correct platform, but all it's doing is creating unnecessary discussion outside of my question. The question wants a proper reason, if it's not a valid flag, the comnent doesn't break any rules, has been posted for a very short time, with a low view count, and helps both the OP and future readers, what is the reason if it is not one or more Moderators acting without care, or attention, or worse still power hungry, or simply overstepping their remit.

Comment: You keep making that claim about "overstepping their remit", but we were basically elected to use our discretion, and there are no rules governing or otherwise specifying which comments must be kept, so we can pretty much delete any comment we want for whatever reason we want without violating any rules or norms. Now, I agree that our choosing to do so would be silly and ultimately harmful to the site, so I hope no one is doing that. If they are, it's reasonable to question why they're doing that. But, really, you'd get a lot further by posting a polite inquiry instead of all this bombast.

Comment: @CodyGray, I assume there are other Moderators. The fact is, you want me to raise the question here, and I've done so, you have not attempted to answer it, just shown other behaviors which are bordering on unfair. You are finding my comments tiresome, and implying I have an ego problem, and even though you've admitted that you could have edited my comment in the linked question, which would have kept this complaint more understandable to others, you decided not to. It suggests your action was based upon your impression of my ego, and your tiredness, not for a valid site improvement purpose.

Comment: I would argue that removing comments based on pure ego is something I do in the interest of site improvement purposes. Anyway, my not answering this question is merely the result of me not having enough information about why the other moderator made the decision that they did. I think it's reasonable to let them weigh in to explain their decision. It's not like this is a time-sensitive matter. And, to address claims of unfairness and/or attempts to hide information to weight the situation in favor of one side or the other, [here are the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUev9.png).

Comment: My question @CodyGray, was not impolite. You may not like that my fifth paragraph 'thought' included possible reasons, but those were certainly not impolite. The comment 'bombast' as you term it, if my understanding is correct, implies you are now calling me pompous, and I'm fairly sure that could be a flaggable comment based upon that alone. You have however explained something which does go some way to answering my question. The deletion of comments seems to be personal discretion, and it is clear that without proper oversight, those elected, cannot be found to have harmed the site.

Comment: Thank you for linking to the removed comment(s) @CodyGray. Please explain the reasoning for 'no longer needed' as it clearly is a valid comment, and makes a very important point. As you can see, when I reposted it, I even changed the wording, to make the same point, but in the hope that the Mod, who may not be an expert in the question tags, wouldn't misunderstand it again. Surely, that said, if a Mod is not sure whether it is valid, then they should be able to 'skip' responsibility, just as we do in the review queues.

Comment: The flag for 'no longer needed' has the following description, "This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.". When a Moderator sees this, they need to determine whether that is true. In this case, unless the question specifically stated that this was for use **only** on English language based systems, I can see no possibility for the flag to be valid. I do not believe that the Moderator in this case has acted according to the description for the flag, and has therefore overstepped the remit.

Comment: If you want my paragraph five theory, I have noted that every time this behavior with comments has occurred over a few years, _(those which are in date, non-conversational and relevant)_, one particular Member has had an interest in that same question post. I might suggest that Member is targeting me by abusing the flag button, and getting help by the Mods due to their lack of time/attention/understanding, or as some sort of favor. I, of course, would not be impolite enough to single that Member out here, but with enough examples, over a long period, would happily make a bet who **User A** is.

Comment: The first line in that last comment on that screenshot is reason enough for me to flag it for deletion. That kind of ranting is completely off-topic on SO.  As far as the NLN flags... A user marked those comments as no longer needed... Supposedly they have served their purpose, and thus are deleted. Such fuss over something that insignificant.

Comment: When Joel Spolsky was asked in 2017 what he would have done differently with Stack Overflow, the first that [came to mind was to auto delete any comment after a week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBDWgWBEbVQ&t=42m30s) or maybe 48 hours (so that it was clear they were intended to be ephemeral). He said [the same in 2018](https://unfiltered.tv/#/detail/48de2202be5c4674b471b51b4b9b289b) (at 50 min 50 secs).

Comment: Though given that the only *realistic* way to add such annotation is through comments, the *gist* of the comment should probably be reinstated. *Ideally*, the OP would react (positively) to a request for such annotation to the question (e.g., *"I suggest adding a note at the end of question, like* *"Note that this example* ***only*** works on Windows systems with Australian English"*. Feel free to rephrase."*), but in most cases the OPs have *zero* interest in building a knowledge repository and it is too much work for them. They wouldn't even respond to such comments (pos. or negatively).

Comment: Perhaps there should be a feature for such annotation, e.g. *"Community notes"* or *"Notes"* (fully editable like the main post, and with its own meta section for working out the contents (or perhaps covered by the existing comment section)). Then normal comments *could* actually be automatically deleted (at least for any new comments).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, whilst I applaud your vision, I fear that it will never be workable. Adding such a feature would inevitably mean more work for the Moderators. My general impression/hope, is that the main cause of the issue at the heart of my post, is the Moderators have too much to do already, hence their lack of time to be through. Now in an ideal world we could say get more Moderators, but I doubt that would help. A better solution might be to just remove commenting completely, and automatically delete all unanswered questions after a decided timeframe, depending upon tag watch popularity.

Answer (score 22):

Comments are second-rate citizens. They're disposable and shouldn't be relied on to last.

If a user flags a comment as "No longer needed", there's a good chance the moderator handling the flag will agree and delete the comment, if the comment has served its purpose.

Business as usual.

Now, reposting that comment isn't that big of a problem if you really think it's necessary...
What **is** a problem, though, is ranting about moderator behavior on SO.
It's off-topic, and likely to get deleted, even if that's just part of the comment.

If you have a problem with how the site is managed, you should contact support or start a discussion here on Meta.

Comment: So, if I have a dislike for another Member, I can just flag their comments as no longer needed and in doing so, I can abuse that member silently, and the Mods will in the majority of cases assist me to do so. If my morals were so inclined, I'd thank you for this information.

Comment: @Compo: How could it be abuse if the ***expectation*** is that comments may be deleted at *any* moment for *any* reason?

Comment: @Compo If you feel someone is abusing you or another user, then the correct action is to raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag on a post and explain what you believe the issue is. Such things would include someone who might be engaged in a *pattern* of flagging specifically your comments. Note that it may take moderators a significant time to handle your flag (the flag queue is quite long at the moment), and you are very unlikely to be provided any information as to the resolution, because moderators don't discuss what, or if, actions are taken wrt. other users.

Comment: @Makyen, I am aware that there is an auto function in place for multiple downvote patterns and probably flags within a short period of time, but this is carefully targeted behavior and has been happening over a long period. I would like to ask, as User A is an obfuscation, can somebody please look into the possible abusive flagging by this same member against me, _(obviously using their real account name, and any previous incarnation of it)_. I would like that to be done as part of this question, it would, after all, identify/confirm a reason, which is what I am seeking.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, the comment, if you read it, makes a point to seek clarification from the OP that their code is for English language systems (the main comment purpose). If they subsequently update their question to clarify that, then the comment would be no longer needed and could be deleted. If they don't, it serves to inform those who view it in future of such a possible flaw, and prevents them from copying flawed code. In general I can agree that many comments could be removed after a agreed site decided timeframe, but not within a couple of hours on one of the quietest days of the week.

Answer (score 13):

Let's [check the FAQ on comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757)

> [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) You should not expect them to be around forever...

There's more that talks about some specific circumstances where comment deletion is warranted but it's already clear from this part that the only way for comments not to be generally around forever would be for moderators to routinely delete them, either as a result of flags or just in passing.

Moderators don't have to rely on flags to act, just because nobody's flagged a post as spam doesn't mean a moderator needs to wait till someone else does so.

So no guidelines or rules have been broken and moderators are acting within their usual remit.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

- It is frustrating to see comments getting deleted that you believe to be of general, long-term interest to others, and if they indeed are, their deletion is to the detriment of the community at large.
- Venting the frustration in comments on SO is inappropriate: flag individual deletions or, if you perceive a pattern, take it to Meta (as you now have) or, if you suspect a particular moderator of malfeasance, contact support.
- Despite the official rules (which deserve updating) minimizing the role of comments:

  - Some are invaluable  and deserve to be kept around indefinitely (except if they're incorporated into the answer, which is always preferable); many others are not and it's important to delete them to minimize the noise.
  - Perhaps self-evidently, justifying deletion by moderators of *any* comment, irrespective of its content, with "we can pretty much delete any comment we want for whatever reason we want" (from a comment on the question) is highly problematic and unlikely to benefit the community at large.
  - While mistakes will continue to be made, especially given how quickly a decision to delete or not to delete must usually be made, let us hope that moderators do fundamentally appreciate that there are comments that provide valuable information and deserve to persist indefinitely, and that past run-ins do not factor into future decisions.

---

I empathize with the frustration underlying your complaint: If you feel you've posted a comment with information of general interest
that may benefit future readers, it is frustrating to see it deleted, especially without feedback as to why.

Good points were made here about how *not* to voice your frustration, namely *as part of your comments*,
and it is arguably justified to delete such comments based on the fact that they contain off-topic venting alone.
Also, repeated off-topic venting is likely to create ill will that may ultimately worsen the situation.

Thus, I think it's best to handle this on a case-by-case basis: If you find a comment that you believe should persist has been
deleted, flag the associated post and explain the problem. (Clearly, comments may also be of an *ephemeral*
nature, and their deletion should be welcomed).

Given that you're suspecting that there is a *pattern* of inappropriate deletions of *your* comments, coming to Meta is the right move (as you have now done), *unless* you have reason to believe that a *specific* moderator is targeting you, in which case you should contact support.

However, some of the comments on your question and one of the answers here betray a
troubling interpretation of the role of comments as *fundamentally* throw-away, based on
relying on the *letter* of the official rules, and/or justifying *any* deletion based
on the grounds that moderators are *allowed* to do so *at their sole discretion*.

While it is unquestionably preferable for comments to be ephemeral and serve only to aid the process
of improving the post at hand itself, upon which they can be deleted, this isn't always an option,
for a variety of reasons.

In practice, there are countless comments out there that have stood the test of time and
have proved invaluable, for several reasons:

They may provide crucial pointers as to how the make the answer work in practice, they may point out that an answer
is obsolete, they may provide relevant *supplemental*  information that may not be relevant to the
*specific* problem but may be relevant to future readers with similar problems, ...

On the flip side, there are many more comments that *are* ephemeral and therefore deserve deletion.

I don't envy moderators for having to separate them wheat from the chaff in a
very short period of time (because they can neither be expected to always have
specific subject-matter expertise nor can they be expected to spend the time to fully
evaluate the post and its comments).

And I'm sure that there are instances of users flagging others' comments with ill intent - though that is sometimes in the eye of the beholder, if there's disagreement over whether
a comment has been addressed in a response comment and/or by an update to the post.

That said, I agree with you that it's better for moderators to err on the side of *not* deleting if there's uncertainty.

In the [case at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUev9.png), I don't think your first comment should have been deleted, because it provided valuable
supplemental information, but I understand why the reposting - despite its better explanation - was deleted due to its off-topic complaint.
Of course I have no control over what will happen, but I encourage you to post it again, with the complaint removed.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. Please note, I have absolutely no issue with the second, and subsequently deleted comment, in theory. I just expected that it, or at least the information pertinent to the question, would have remained in place, until after this question had been answered/aired. At least Cody posted an image later for that purpose. I thought about reposting it, but frankly I've spent too much time trying to help others, and based upon this experience on Meta, if those elected just want to gang up on critics and delete whatever they want to its detriment, I'm wasting my time.

Comment: For what it's worth, I fundamentally agree with this answer. All of this. I am on record, on countless occasions, as speaking out against what has effectively become a meme at this point about comments being "ephemeral" (that's literally not even true). I recognize that there are countless useful comments that should not be deleted, even if their being posted is not strictly within the bounds of what comments are intended to be used for (e.g., requesting clarification). I don't believe in shooting ourselves in the foot by removing useful information (e.g., answers posted in the comments).

Comment: I handle comment flags in the way that Shog9 once recommended, a very long time ago now. Basically, if I can't figure out within a very short period of time why the comment is no longer needed and/or is inappropriate, then I won't delete it. A couple of "extra" comments outliving their usefulness doesn't cause any real issues, and, to me, it is preferable than accidentally deleting useful stuff. If there's something I missed, someone will reflag, hopefully offering more of a compelling justification/explanation. That's not to say I don't delete comments, ofc. I've deleted nearly 100k of them.

Comment: It's not anywhere close to impossible that mistakes can get made in the process of handling comment flags, and that's not even getting into differences of opinion. I have, multiple times, overridden the deletion of a comment by another moderator and subsequently brought to my attention (in other words, I've undeleted deleted comments). But jumping out of the gate with accusations of mods being derelict in their duty, and of engaging some kind of conspiracy, being "power-hungry"…this causes me to flip the "bozo bit". Whether you want an individual comment or pattern reviewed, ask nicely.

Comment: @CodyGray; the main issue, is certainly with **User A**, misusing flags, probably for ill will reasons, (as there was no justification). The sub issues, are either **1.** **Moderator A** is complicit, (knowingly assisting **User A**), or **2.** **User A** is exploiting general Moderator behaviors, (their lack of time, care or attention, or belief that comments are throw away at their sole discretion, even to the sites' detriment). I believe I'm the victim of the main issue, not all of the site Moderators, so yes please, as I've already asked Makyen, I would like to know which of those is true.

Comment: Did you do as Makyen suggested and raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag on a post, explaining that you think "User A" is inappropriately targeting you/your comments with flags, which is leading to legitimate comments being deleted by unsuspecting moderators? (For some context: flagged comments are listed on a mod dashboard to review. We don't necessarily see that the same user has flagged them. If there *was* some type of serial abuse of comment flags, we could easily not notice. That's why it's reasonable for you to bring this to our attention so we can investigate.) @Compo

Comment: @Cody, not as yet. My underlying reason for that has been, it does not seem correct for me to flag a question or answer, when that questioner, or answerer, has not done anything which deserves their submission to have been flagged. Additionally, when such an occurence happens, and I notice it, within a short timeframe, inevitably, (as most of Members, Mods here tend to visit in shifts), the Moderator first getting to the flag for action, is likely to be the same one who has just deleted the comment. It's clear to me already that Mods, especially the 'accused', would ignore and close that flag.

Comment: @Compo Flagging someone's post (for moderator intervention) is not a punishment; it does not affect them in any way. A moderator might take an action that affects the user and/or their post but the flag itself. Because the system doesn't provide a way for users to directly contact the moderators team about a general issue, it's a known workaround to flag _any_ post and explain the problem. You could flag one of your own posts so that you don't involve other users' content.

Comment: I did not know that, I could flag something of my own, in order to prevent a flag potentially affecting an innocent party. Thank you for that information @41686d6564standsw.Palestine. (I suppose I could just a flag User A post too)! However, as I'm not satisfied that the Moderator receiving it, would not be the self-same on who'd invoked the deletion, (for reasons already stated). I'd have to leave it for some time before doing so. Still, I'm not sure why, if there's no system for doing so, this process cannot have already happened using this question as the same kind of workaround.